# Accessing Drupal array values

Tags: entities, commerce

I'm noobing my way through countless websites trying to find an answer to accessing a value in a Commerce field array.

I somehow managed to throw together the following code to retrieve a value for a workflow rule I'm writing:

```
$product_id = $current_line_item->commerce_product;
```

The result is: `array(1) { ["und"]=> array(1) { [0]=> array(1) { ["product_id"]=> string(2) "14" } } }`

I can't figure out how to get any deeper into the array than that. I need to return the product_id value in this array.

Can anyone guide me on the best way to do this?

Comment: `$product_id['und'][0]['product_id']` will get you what you need, but I don't think it's the proper/recommended way to do it.  Try this: https://drupalcommerce.org/developer-guide/utilizing-core-apis/working-entity-metadata-wrappers.  And if you can provide some more code (lines before this) it might help.

Comment: "I can't figure out how to get any deeper into the array than that." is a plain PHP question: Drupal doesn't have a special syntax to access PHP arrays. Even if you were using the proper Drupal function, you would still have an array to access. You could use the Entity API module, since that is a requirement for the Drupal Commerce module.

Comment: While researching Patrick's option below, I found here (https://www.computerminds.co.uk/articles/rendering-drupal-7-fields-right-way) that method is not recommended.

The author suggested using this method instead:
$node = node_load($nid);
$field = field_get_items('node', $node, 'field_name');
$output = field_view_value('node', $node, 'field_name', $field[$delta]);

Comment: More on the comment above...

Further research found that node_load has been deprecated in favor of EntityFieldQuery.

Would anyone be able to provide some examples of how I can use this to get the "product_id" value I'm trying to get?

Answer (score 1):

[Devel](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel) is super useful to help you figure out these type of things.

Once enabled, you can write `dpm($product_id)` and it will print out a nice organized structure of the array.  From there, you can click on any item and it will show you how you can access the item like `['und'][0]['product_id']` in your example.

Depending on what exactly you're trying to do, there may be different ways to get the info you need.

Comment: The OP knows already the array structure.

Comment: Thanks Patrick.

I prefer not to use UND to get the value as that seems to be the least recommended method from my research. 

EntityFieldQuery seems to be the way to go but it's over my head right now. I'm just not clear how to format the query to get the value I need as mentioned in my original post.

Comment: @CraigL. I think you're adding a little unnecessary complexity to a simple task.  The data that you're trying to grab is already loaded - no reason to create another DB query.  If you're worried about using `"und"` because you plan on doing translations in the future, you can simply replace `"und"` with the `LANGUAGE_NONE` constant so when you do add translations, everything still works properly.